# Clojure seq as a substitute for Scala Option[T]

Tags: scala, clojure, sequence, scala-option

Scala offers a hierarchy of classes `Option[T]`, `Some[T] extends Option[T]`, and `None extends Option[Nothing]` that I have found useful for wrapping Java method calls that can return `null`, among other things:

```
val result = Option(someJavaMethodThatReturnsNull())
```

`result` acts like a sequence of zero or one items, depending on whether the Java method returned an object or `null`. `Option` has methods like `map`, `filter`, etc. that you can use just like those on a sequence and either return a new sequence (`Some`), if the original was `Some[T]`, or `None` if the original was `None`.

It appears that the Clojure function `seq` behaves similarly: `(seq x)` will be a sequence of one item if x is non-null or `nil` if x is null. This value can then be passed to `(map ...)`, `(filter ...)`, etc., just like the Scala `Option` methods.

Am I missing something? Does this pattern make sense? Is this a "Eureka!" moment that is obvious to experienced Clojure programmers?

Comment: A side note: This shared structure of collections and options (and more) is captured in Haskell through the [Functor](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Functor.html) and [Foldable](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html) classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `seq` will either return an abstract, sequential view on a collection in case the collection is non-empty. `nil` otherwise. So it is completely unrelated to what you want. However you can use `nil` in if tests. eg.

```
(when-let [thing (.someMethodThatReturnsSomethingOrNil other-thing)]
  (run-only-when thing is-not-nil-or-false))
```

Is that what you intend?

*Edit:* Beware the false.

Comment: But most (all?) of the Clojure functions that operate on sequences accept `nil`: `(map nil)`, etc. At the "end-of-the-line" of functions, you may need to test for nil, but in a chain if calls, you can just pass along what the previous function returned.

Comment: But `seq` doesn't help you, since an arbitrary object is not seqable. `map` and friends work on a different level than the `Option` stuff. I found it easier to write a function `nil`-safe and then just use `->` and `comp`. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

You always could use the [maybe monad](http://onclojure.com/2009/03/05/a-monad-tutorial-for-clojure-programmers-part-1/), which is close to scala Option (and haskell Maybe) without static type safety of course.

Also there is [the family of ? threading functions](http://clojure.github.com/clojure-contrib/core-api.html#clojure.contrib.core/-?%3E) (.?. is the better choice for java interop)

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly use a Clojure sequence to represent zero, one or more return values.

It is a sensible approach and very idiomatic if your function is actually expected to return a collection.

However I would *not* recommend using a sequence to emulate an option type. This is likely to confuse users of your API. In Clojure, the normal and idiomatic way to is just to return nil if a value is not available, and return the value directly if it is.

Compare:

```
  (if-let [a (function-that-returns-nil-or-result)]
    (do-something-with a))
```

With what you would need if you used a sequence to emulate an option type:

```
  (if-let [a (function-that-returns-a-possibly-empty-sequence)]
    (do-something-with (first a)))
```

I definitely prefer the first option.... why do we need or want the API user to unpack the result from the sequence with `first`?

In general, nil works pretty well in Clojure (much better than in other languages) because:

- All the library functions interpret nil as an empty sequence, so you are much less likely to run into NullPointerExceptions.
- nil is also considered "falsey" so can be conveniently used in boolean operations.

Answer (score 0):

`(seq x)` will return `nil` if `x` is `nil` or an empty collection. However, `map`, `filter` etc. will accept `nil` as their collection argument (i.e., they won't break) and return an empty sequence. This may give the result that you expect from Scala's `Option` statement.

The following will each return an empty sequence:

```lisp
(map (fn [x] x) (seq nil))
(map (fn [x] x) (seq `()))
(filter even? (seq nil))
(filter even? (seq `()))
```